# Games unable to connect to the internet

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I have a Samsung galaxy Ace, rooted.

I installed Final Fantasy Dimensions and Sandbox (both are games). They require intial net connection for registration, but I get an `unable to connect to network` every time.

I am using Wi-Fi. Downloading and browsing via browser works. So, why is the internet not working for the games?

Answer (score 0):

The port the games are using might be blocked at the router level. 
Here are your options:

1. Try using 3G or 4G
2. or make sure that you are allowing traffic (TCP/UDP) on the correct unprivileged ports (1025 and up) through your router.

Comment: Or possibly the OP is running some kind of firewall in which the app needs to be granted permission to access the network?

Comment: i even tried the 3g network but nothing happened.....other net apps like whatapp is working but only the games are having the problem.